# Why can't Ms Access find referenced form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, runtime-error

I'm building a database in which I keep records of employees I work with. When someone is logged into the database and opens the form containing an employee's information, the shouldn't be able to change that information. So when the form opens, all the fields should be visible, but disabled. The code I use is:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Pers_Toev", , , "[PersID]=" & [lstPers], acFormEdit, acDialog
Forms!frm_Pers_Toev!Naam.Enabled = False
```

When I run this code, the form opens properly, but the field isn't disabled. Instead, I get the runtime error 2450 "Microsoft Access cannot find the referenced form "frm_Pers_Toev".

I use the same sort of method for different forms and then it works fine.

What can I do?

Comment: Use it on form `frm_pers_toev` on open event than it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that that same form is used to add new employee's information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the form not in Dialog mode

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Pers_Toev", , , "[PersID]=" & [lstPers], acFormEdit
```

Otherwise the code stops execution until the form closed

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could leave `acDialog` as it is, place your code in the Form `frm_Pers_Toev` load event:-

```
 Naam.Enabled = False
```